# Mbed OS -> is it really open source?

Tags: mbed

If Mbed OS is open source then why do you have to use a cloud compiler to compile the software?  Is the source code for Mbed OS open but the the cloud compiler is closed source?

Just looking for clarification amongst marketing jargon.

SW

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be some confusion here between Mbed OS which is a open source project and the Mbed Compiler Service, which is a tool that makes getting started with Mbed OS super easy.

Mbed OS is open source, you can find it here : http://github.com/armmbed/mbed-os, i encourage you to contribute by submitting a Pull Request.

The online compiler service is run by the Arm Mbed team to provide an easy way to get started with compiling your programs (there are some assumptions and sensible defaults in place so everything 'just works'). You can export your programs to a 3rd party compiler like Keil, IAR, or GCC / Eclipse for debugging if you need it. You can also use Mbed CLI offline to compile your code using GCC. (Fun fact, Mbed CLI is the same set of command line tools the online compiler uses).

Additional fun fact, the online compiler is using armcc (the same one that comes with Keil) where as GCC is the default for Mbed CLI (though if you have a liscense for armcc or iarcc you can use those with Mbed CLI as well.

Answer (score 0):

Mbed OS is completely open source. There are various options to compile. So far, there are 3 toolchains that are supported by ARM mbed:

1. GCC ARM
2. ARMCC
3. IAR

Out of these 3, only GCC ARM is free while others have free evaluation versions with limited features unless you buy them.

In short, you can download mbed OS and then compile it for a target using any of the toolchains which may or may not be open source.